# How to handle a user on Stack Overflow who ducks your questions if you do not accept his replies?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I am encountering a really ill mannered fellow who has lots of reputation points. He does not contribute to any of my questions other than insult the people who reply to me and confuse the issues. And heaven help me if I disagree with him on points extraneous to the topic of the question. I immediately get ducked for questions which are unique and valid.

Is there a mechanism to block such users from crashing in on the nice people who try to help?

Comment: Flag his comments for moderator attention. Also, consider avoiding language that tends to inject emotion into an otherwise technical question/answer session.

Comment: As long as it's done politely, it's entirely appropriate for a user to spend their time commenting on problems with questions, helping you figure out how to improve them, even if they then leave it to other users to answer the question after it has been improved.  While this can seem insulting, and it occasionally can be, you should work to recognize that such users are almost always trying to *help you* by making your question better.  (And if they aren't, you're better off assuming that they are anyway.)

Comment: I have to say I'm confused, I looked at the last 10 questions you posted and don't see a single conflict or issue.

Comment: I avoid him as much as possible.  But if I engage him I have to walk on tip toes!  He has already blocked my account on valid questions.  Fortunately, my questions received points and after a while my account was unblocked!  Am I frustrated???  You bet!

Comment: No, it's not him. The downvotes here are from people who disagree with your approach and adjectives.

Comment: @DennisKean Your account would never have been blocked because of one user; it'll have been blocked because the community as a whole found your contributions to be more harmful than helpful.  The number of votes you'd need to be blocked is more than one user could give.

Comment: I apologize for calling out an adjstive @Sha Wiz Dow Ard.  But I did not name him by UserID to make the connection, neither do I intend to do so.  An insult has to have a target to leave the abstraction of theoretics.  But if it offends anyone, I understand.

Comment: @Servy Fortunately, the community bailed me out!  If you really want to find out who it is you can look at the few leftover negative balanced questions and check who participates in them.  But I do not need to tell you that.  Right?

Comment: @DennisKean The fact that you were question banned at all makes it clear to me that your problem is with you, not with one user.  It's an indication that you are not asking questions that are up to the standards of this community.  That you are taking it personally and responding negatively when someone attempts to assist you with improving your questions is further indication, in my eyes, that the problem is not with some other user, but with you.  You need to learn how to accept constructive criticism of your questions and to make the improvements requested by others.

Comment: @Joe,  Like I said, I avoid him and ignore him, but that does not help.  If I forego his replies, none of which are helpful, I get ducked.  If I reply and question his reply, he ducks me before anyone has a chance to make up their mind on the worthiness of the question.  And that starts a cascade.  But he is one of the first to reply and suggest bad ideas.  So, what am I to do.  You guys need to  recognize that power in the hands of malice does not translate to a democracy.

Comment: I'd also suggest that you ought to consider answering a few questions, not just asking.  You've got over 30 questions, with no answers that were not to your own questions.  The site tolerates an awful lot more from people who are helpful to others, than solely ask for help.

Comment: @DennisKean Looking through several of your questions I'm seeing a lot of helpful constructive comments that you're ignoring.  I know when I see users that start to clearly ignore helpful and constructive comments it indicates that they're not worth working with; it'll be too much work to try to get enough out of them to try to answer, so I'll just not try.

Comment: I am not aware of 30 questions pending.  Maybe you can show me where to find that list.  I am not a frequent user of SO and I will gladly answer any question which people pose to me.  That is not by omission nor self centeredness.  If you would be so kind as to show me that list every question will be answered ASAP!

Comment: So is this just a rant or do you have a specific example?

Comment: @Dooeknob, Are you addressing me?

Comment: @Doorknob  As I said before, I do not get into disputes with this guy, but when he participates he wants positive feedback even though he is dead wrong.  The price is a negative score.  I know how to avoid problems, but now he is appearing in every question I ask.  And I can't avoid him?

Comment: That still doesn't help. Please give a specific example.

Comment: @Doorknob   I do not have examples, nor will you find any examples of me treating him adversely in public.  I am smart enough to know how to avoid getting into these problems.  And that is why I came to you for help.  So, your wish to implicate me somehow is irrelevant.  I figured that out and hold it as a policy of my behavior.  I came to you because this fellow is a menace.  So, sorry for starving you of content which may give you a high, potentially.  There is nothing in my behavior toward him to condemn me for.  And that is why I am so upset.

Comment: And what of that list of 30 questions hanging in my closet, @Servy?  An allegation should have at least some backbone?  Where is this list of 30 questions pending in my closet?  Or was that just a hyperbole?

Comment: If you don't give us a specific example, how do we know what you're talking about?

Comment: @Doorknob Calling out specific users is really not necessary. Ultimately the answer will not be different from what I've already said. Ignore, or let moderators handle it. That said, Dennis, you might want to keep some of your attitude here on Meta in check. Even if you're upset, we're merely trying to figure out what happened and how to help you. That is why Doorknob asked for the information. Not to get "a high".

Comment: @Bart  I am glad you intercepted here.  I have no intention of trashing anyone in specific in public and behind his back.  Hence this was a hypothetical question.  

Thank you for your mature attitude.  You may be the only one who understood this delicate point, but I'm glad to have met you.

Comment: @DennisKean I never said anything about 30 questions pending, only you did.  I said that I went through several of your questions and found helpful and constructive comments that you were ignoring.  I didn't say any where questions (although some are), and a didn't give any exact number.  That you're acting as if I'm insulting you instead of taking my comments constructively is only further indication in my mind that the user you're referring to is most likely acting appropriately and helpfully, and that you simply aren't able to accept the constructive criticism.

Comment: @Servy  How does one answer every question which comes along, when many people reply at the same time and you take in their examples and test them on the fly.  I need two secretaries to help me out to reply adequately.  I do my best to reply and thank anyone who contributes, especially those who give a cogent reply.  But I will make more of an effort in the future.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Thank you for the advice...

Comment: @DennisKean If you're asking so many questions that you aren't able to keep up with the clarifying questions asked of you then you're asking too many questions.  If you have more than a few recent pending questions at any given time then it's a pretty strong sign that you should be putting more time and effort trying to solve your problems before asking.  You don't need to thank people that reply; that's not particularly helpful, what's concerning to me is people pointing out problems in your questions or suggesting you fix things and you not making those fixes or adding the info.

Comment: I was referring to each individual question, Servy.  I know that you need to find something wrong with me, to validate your negative comments, but I look at every reply and try every suggestion.  There is no way for you to conclude that I am not testing those fixes.  Your assertion alone shows your attempt to cross the boundary to implicate me in something negative.  My questions are occasionally quite complex and some people try to supply primitive answers.  I look at them but some are obviously not well thought out.  Others come in way after the discussion is over, like a day later.

Comment: @DennisKean - I should make a note that after looking at my very detailed tools here, I see no user who has targeted you with downvotes at any point. The person you are accusing of this is innocent, and all of the comments I see in the last year on your questions are either trying to clarify the question or trying to help you. I see no evidence of abusive behavior here at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not block a specific users from participating in your posts.

Let's assume for a moment that this user really is not bringing up valid points and exhibits troll like behaviour.

The first thing to do would be to simply ignore him. Don't debate. Don't try to argue and make a point. Simply ignore. Anything other than that is only fuel on the fire. You can't win and will only be frustrated as a result.

Now, if this user persists, flag. There is no need for you to handle the situation. If things get out of hand, flag one of your posts for moderator attention and, using the "other" flag option, explain the situation. If it has a long history, add some relevant links or tell them to look deep into the issue. And that's it. Move on.

If the user would be serially downvoting you, you don't have to do anything. Such events are usually automatically rolled back. But it seems that's not happening to you to begin with.

That being said, without knowing the exact details of your situation, try taking a step back and evaluate if this user doesn't have a point. If he doesn't, fair enough. Move on. If he does, even if he happens to formulate it unpleasantly, take it into account.

And that's all there is to it. Ignore or flag, and move on.

Comment: Thank you @Bart.  That is the correct answer to my question, though sadly unfavorable.  But your reply is very appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. It's really all you can and need to do. No matter how frustrated you might feel.

Comment: I did not know that I could flag an exchange.  Thank you for that.  Also, could you please tell me where those questions to me can be found, which Joe alleges that I did not answer.  I want to take care of that and keep my account clean as I can.